# Add parent field in django admin forms

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here are my two models:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    provider_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    accounts = models.ManyToManyField('Account', blank=True)
    data_types = models.ManyToManyField('DataType', blank=True,
                                        through='ProviderDataType')

class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    prefixes = models.ManyToManyField('AccountPrefix', blank=True)
```

Here is my admin.py

```
class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', '__unicode__')

class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__')


admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to have a selection of the parent provider when I try to add or update my account model and upon saving it. The Parent model has already set the account on its manytomany field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can use [TubularInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models). Like this:

```
class ProviderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Provider.accounts.through
    extra = 1

class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProviderInline,]
    ...
```

Comment: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression,, this is the error after I added one account click the Provider model section in the admin

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada this is weird. Are you sure you didn't have this error before adding admin inlines? Can you provide full traceback.

Comment: Never mind, it's an error in my end.. Thanks for the solution!